# Regular expression for "Url Cannot start with a '/' or '~', Cannot contain a '?' character""

Tags: regex

**Edit:**

Could anyone help me write :(here is one answer)
Could Try:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^([^\?~/])([^\?])*\s*$",ErrorMessage = "Url Cannot start with a '/' or '~', Cannot contain a '?' character")]
```

and

```
[RegularExpression(@"^/.*\s*$", ErrorMessage = "Route Url must start with '/'")]
```

Comment: I tried ^(?!/).+   but I am new to regular expression, hope someone could help me how to include another character"~" and another requirement....

Comment: Ah. That's close. The caret `^` marks the start of a string when it's not used inside square braces `[]`, though. Also, parentheses `()` match a group, what you want is square braces (which match any element in a set). The kind of string you're matching there is:

?!/asdfkefasdf

what you want is
/[^~/][^?]+/

which will match anything except `~` or `/` for the first character and then anything but a ? afterwards.

Comment: Thanks..I think I tried /[^~/][^?]+/ but if I put '~' inside the string like"inde~x" will be an error

Comment: Well of course. The regex I wrote should do what you said you wanted, not what you secretly wanted and didn't explain.

Comment: sorry about that. i will try to learn more..

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite tell if this is one question or two. "Url cannot start with a '/' AND must start with '/' are mutually exclusive.

Assuming it's two questions.

1) The regular expression for:  must NOT start with '/' or '~'   is

```
/^[^\/~]/
```

if you are using normal slash delimiters '/'. If you are using Perl REs with alternate delimiters you can simplify slightly to-

```
m|^[^/~]|
```

because you don't have to escape the slash inside the character class.

2) The RE for:  must start with slash   is

```
/^\//
```

Regards: colin_e